# OnItemClickListener un fragment doesn't work

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, onitemclicklistener

I have a probleme when using onItemClickListener un Fragment.
Here is my code

```
list.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p1, View p2, int p3, long p4) {
       Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   };
});
```

```
Which return the error : method android.widget.AdapterView<>.OnItemClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener) in android.view.ListView' cannot be applied to (com.package.name.MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment(anonymous)).`
```

**Edit :** The code above is in the OnCreateView of the Fragment, and there's a rootView Variable.

Comment: you are using wrong method.. you should use `setOnItemClickListener()`

Answer (score 4):

Use `setOnItemClickListener` instead of `setOnClickListener` as:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p1, View p2, int p3, long p4) {
    // ItemClick/ItemSelect Code
    }    
});
```

Because you are passing `OnItemClickListener` listener in setOnClickListener. if you want to set `setOnClickListener` for ListView then pass `OnClickListener` `anonymous` class to `setOnClickListener` method of ListView.